# 3.3 V fingerprint sensor to 5 V USB

Tags: usb, level-shifting

I recycled a fingerprint sensor from an HP Pavilion DV7 laptop that had mainboard issues. I would like to use the fingerprint sensor on my main PC.

After looking at the schematics, it appears to be a 3.3 V/5 V USB device. It requires both voltages, but I don't know why. I think one is for the LED (for scanning, not an indicator) and the other voltage is for the logic chip itself.

I can't get my pc to detect it. This is the pinout from the block diagram of the notebook itself:

[image]

To try to connect it to my PC, I used a bidirectional 2-channel logic level adapter between the sensor and my PC. This is my wiring:

[image]

Sometimes, the LEF lights up when I touch the sensor, but my PC won't recognize anything. Can someone help me figure out why it's not being detected? AFAIK, the sensor works.

Comment: If it just needs 5V and 3V supply, then why did you connect a bidirectional level shifter for supply and data pins? It can't shift power and USB data does not need shifting as it is not 5V and connecting something weird to your PC data pins can damage your PC.

Comment: I actually didnt know that. As i'm very familiar with serial connections, i thought that it would be a similar thing. I bypassed the logic level shifter and it instantly got detected by my pc. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sometimes, the LEF lights up when I touch the sensor, but my PC won't
> recognize anything. Can someone help me figure out why it's not being
> detected?

The first thing would be to take the breadboard out of the equation. Breadboards have 10's of pFs of parasitic capacitance, which would create problems for the differential bus of USB. Also worth mentioning is parasitic contact resistance of the breadboard, which could be dropping the voltage to the device. I would try soldering it direct.

It's also unclear from the schematic why you would need a level shifter for a differential USB bus, if the fingerprint reader is connecting via USB then it should be connected to the data pins. If it is another bus like serial then use a serial converter.